# must the subspace which orthogonal projection onto be closed?

Tags: real-analysis

As we know orthogonal projection theorem is based on the premise that the subspace is closed(at least in stein's book),but I encountered an exercise in stein's real analysis which seems to say nothing about whether closeness is needed or not[image]

As far as the exercise itself concerned,the operator $P$ project exactly onto $S$,while $S$ seems not necessarily closed because $L^2(R^d)$ is infinite dimensional.So where is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ is closed. If $f_n \in S$ for each $n$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^{2}$ the there is a subsquence $f_{n_k}$ converging a.e. to $f$ and this implies $f=0$ a.e. on the complement of $E$.

Comment: If in this exercise E is measure zero,is $L^2(E)$ complete?I know if E is positive measure,it's complete

Comment: You are mis-interpreting the question. $E$ just any measurable set and $S$ consists of all $L^{2}$ functions $f$ such that $\{x \notin E: f(x) \neq 0\}$ has measure $0$. @math